# Is it possible to apply the primary key of the row as an id attribute to each <td> when using django-tables2?

Tags: django, model, primary-key, django-tables2

With django-tables2, i am trying to set the id of each element of my model as an "attribute" of every single `<td>` corresponding to a specific `<tr>`.

I'm using a dict in the Column Attributes definition like so:

```
class MainTable(tables.Table):
    id = tables.Column()
    Client = tables.Column(attrs={'td': {
        'data-name': 'Client',
        'data-type': 'text',
        'data-pk': lambda record: record.pk,     
        'data-url': 'path/to/url',
        'data-placeholder': 'New Client',
        'data-title': 'New Client' }})
```

Every attribute is applying correctly except the 'data-pk'. Is there a way to get the primary key inside the dict? Or any other way to set this attribute using django-tables2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot do that on columns, but you can on [rows](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html?highlight=row-attrs#row-attributes):

```
class Table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        row_attrs = {
            'data-pk': lambda record: record.pk
        }
```

Which might make more sense anyway, since a record is mapped to a row, not to a single table cell in a row.

I can see the use for computable `attr`s with arguments on table columns, so if you decide you need it, you are welcome to [open a Pull request](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/pulls).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jieter . I made it by customizing the table.html of django-tables2. Had to include it inside the <td> tag:
 `<td  {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }} pk="{{ row.record.id }}">`